# Is there a shortcut for switching pivot point?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

Is there a shortcut for switching pivot point? I tried looking in user preferences, but I wasn't sure what to type in there.

Comment: That is the most convoluted shortcut I know in Blender. I have seen worse though: on some Windows boxes I have had to log in we had to do [ctrl] + [shift] + [alt] + Ö.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>,</kbd> : Bounding Box Center

<kbd>.</kbd> : 3D Cursor

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> : Individual Origins

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> : Toggle Manipulate center points

[image]

If you want to customize the shortcuts, open the *Blender User Preferences* > *Input*, set the Filter Type "Key-Binding" and type <kbd>,</kbd> in the search field.

[image]

[image]

You'll find the list of the Assignement Values here:

http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html?highlight=bounding_box_center#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.pivot_point

Answer (score 0):

There is: it is (by default) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  <kbd>C</kbd>. (I don't know about OSX-speaking s. It could be different.)

Comment: Actually, the key shortcut given, [ctrl] + [shift] + [alt] + c, is a shortcut for changing the position of the origin, the original poster was asking about a shortcut for changing the pivot point, so this is not an answer to the question..

Comment: Sorry, is that the gizmo in the lower header of the 3D view near the proportional editing stuff?

Comment: No. That's the second button to the right of the object interaction mode selection box (where you select "object mode", "edit mode", "sculpt mode", "texture paint", &c). The next button to the right is the button for selection of the display mode (wireframe, solid, textured, &c), and the _next_ button is the pivot point selector.

Comment: OK, have a look at these (I am not near any computer right now. If these work I will add them to my answer.): http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Pivot_Point. Go through the links. The hotkeys are listed for every possible state.

Comment: I don't know how current these are (I believe that <kbd>.</kbd> centers the view for example.)